# 3d plot with ksdensity in matlab

Tags: matlab, math, plot

I have a problem in matlab.

I used a ksdensity function on a vector of deltaX, which was my computed X minus actual X.
And I did the same on deltaY.

Then I used plot on that data. This gave me two 2d plots.

As I have two plots showing how (in)accurate was my system in computing X and Y (something like gaussian bell it was). Now I would like to have one plot but in 3d.
The code was just like that:

```
    [f,xi] = ksdensity(deltaX);
            figure;
            plot(xi,f)
```

Comment: you could try making a mesh() plot. Type "help mesh"

Comment: "mesh(x,y,Z) and mesh(x,y,Z,C), with two vector arguments replacing
    the first two matrix arguments, must have length(x) = n and
    length(y) = m where [m,n] = size(Z).  In this case, the vertices
    of the mesh lines are the triples (x(j), y(i), Z(i,j)).
    Note that x corresponds to the columns of Z and y corresponds to
    the rows."

This is what seems to interest me, although I have a problem with Z.

Comment: @willpower2727 and the problem is that:
ks density returns a pair [xi,f] where f are just the corresponding to x propability density function values. So I have 4 vectors of 100 elements and 0 matrixes. Docs say I need Z martrix. I'm trying to work it out but any help will be more than welcome!

Comment: @ adam please see my answer and let me know how else I can help, to be honest I'm not sure about the mathematically correct way to visualize your problem in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Ok what I'm about to show is probably not the correct way to visualize your problem, mostly because I'm not quite sure I understand what you're up to. But this will show you an example of how to make the Z matrix as discussed in the comments to your question.

Here's the code:

```
x = wgn(1000,1,5);%create x and y variables, just noise
y = wgn(1000,1,10);
[f,xi] = ksdensity(x);%compute the ksdensity (no idea if this makes real-world sense)
[f2,xi2] = ksdensity(y);

%create the Z matrix by adding together the densities at each x,y pair
%I doubt this makes real-world sense
for z=1:length(xi)
for zz = 1:length(xi2)
        Z(z,zz) = f(z)+f2(zz);
    end
end

figure(1)
mesh(xi,xi2,Z)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

I leave it up to you to determine the correct way to visualize your density functions in 3D, this is just how you could make the Z matrix. In short, the Z matrix contains the plot elevation at each x,y coordinate. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: thank you very much! actually I don't have my matlab with me right now, but I will test it soon.
However I was thinking about correctness of this solution and I think it is correct. At first I wasn't confident, but I re-thinked that, and then again, and again, and seems like this is exactly what I need to plot :)